# Поиск по переменной

Tags: vb.net

скажите пожалуйса как сделать поиск по текстовой переменной а именно найти там текст "http://" и удалить его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Str = Replace(Str, Value, "")
```

Value - ваша переменная.